# How to change the terminal in windows to a custom one

Tags: terminal

I want to change the cmd or powershell in windows to a custom executable file created by me as a terminal that can run windows command.
How can i do it

Comment: How to change the default terminal emulator on Windows (cmd). `https://superuser.com/questions/509642/how-to-change-the-default-terminal-emulator-on-windows-cmd`

Comment: ask your question here https://superuser.com/